# Vaadin 14 Typescript component with sound recording ability

Tags: typescript, upload, getusermedia, vaadin-flow, lit

I trying to create a simple Vaadin component (like Button) that reacts on press and release events. On press event it must start sound record from microphone and on release it must upload recorded data to the backend. I think that is good choice for uploading is use Upload Vaadin component. I found examples of how to record and play recorded data on page, but i cannot find a way how to start collect it with Upload component. And i am not sure that if create component for Vaadin 14 + Lit it will be useful in next LTS releases. Please point me how to start develop my component.

Found npm for sound record: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mrmaruf/recordrtc)

And for creating Lit-component: [link](https://jcgueriaud1.github.io/components/ts-lit-element/)

Or maybe there is some other possibilies, like custom StreamResource that will send recorded data from browser to backend without using Upload class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found nice project and make a copy with some changes: [link](https://github.com/parttio/VCamera/)